# Creating a File Share Server with Internet Access and Security

Tags: apache2, internet, samba, file-sharing, file-server

I am trying to create a file share server for my friends and I to store and share video.  I want my friends to be able browse the share in the Windows Explorer and mount it as a network drive if they so choose. I have looked at Apache File Servers and other options, but I just can't get a feeling what's the right path.

Requirements:  Usernames and Passwords for each individual person.
Encryption of Username/Password and Files in Transit (SSL should be fine)
Must not require additional software for Windows systems accessing the server over the internet.

I have looked at Apache, Samba, OwnCloud, and others, and nothing seems quite right.  I am just looking for a bit of guidance before I start installing and wasting time testing things that won't work.

Comment: Check out unRaid!